# Optimizing Script for Downloading Files from Library with Folders

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint, scripting

Due to some extenuating circumstances we had to resort to migrating a teams content from one farm to another via locally downloading the files from their lists and shipping them. Unfortunately, this team used folders in their lists VERY heavily. And they wanted to maintain their folder structure for document organization purposes, so I had to come up with a script that could download the contents of a list, folders and all, while also maintaining that folder structure. I have years of SP admin experience, but my PS scripting has always been very basic to intermediate usage at best so I am reaching out to you all to help me optimize this script.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$w=get-spweb "http://URL"
$tlfolder=$w.getfolder("Old_Surveys")
$subfold=$tlfolder.subfolders|select *|?{$_.name -match "historical"}
$subfolders=$subfold.subfolders
foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
{
    new-item -path "D:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys" -name $subfolder.name -itemtype "directory"

    #if the 2 level sub folder exists
    if ($subfolder.subfolders -ne $null)
    {
        $subfoldername=$subfolder.name

        $subsubfolders=$subfolder.subfolders
        foreach ($subsubfolder in $subsubfolders)
        {
            new-item -path "D:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys\$subfoldername" -name $subsubfolder.name -itemtype "directory"

            # if the 3 level sub folder exists
            if ($subsubfolder.subfolders -ne $null)
            {
                $subsubfoldername=$subsubfolder.name

                $subsubsubfolders=$subsubfolder.subfolders
                foreach ($subsubsubfolder in $subsubsubfolders)
                    {
                        new-item -path "D:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys\$subfoldername\$subsubfoldername" -name $subsubsubfolder.name -itemtype "directory"

                        #if the 3 level sub files exists
                        if ($subsubsubfolder.files -ne $null)
                        {
                            $subsubsubfiles=$subsubsubfolder.files
                            $subsubsubfoldername=$subsubsubfolder.name
                            foreach ($subsubsubfile in $subsubsubfiles)
                                {
                                    write-host $subsubsubfile.name
                                    $b=$subsubsubfile.openbinary()
                                    $fs=new-object system.io.filestream(("d:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys\$subfoldername\$subsubfoldername\$subsubsubfoldername"+$subsubsubfile.name), [system.io.filemode]::create)
                                    $bw=new-object system.io.binarywriter($fs)
                                    $bw.write($b)
                                    $bw.close()
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
            if ($subsubfolder.files -ne $null)
                   {
                        $subsubfiles=$subsubfolder.files
                        $subsubfoldername=$subsubfolder.name
                        foreach ($subsubfile in $subsubfiles)
                            {
                                write-host $subsubfile.name
                                $b=$subsubfile.openbinary()
                                $fs=new-object system.io.filestream(("d:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys\$subfoldername\$subsubfoldername\"+$subsubfile.name), [system.io.filemode]::create)
                                $bw=new-object system.io.binarywriter($fs)
                                $bw.write($b)
                                $bw.close()
                            }
                    }
             }
        if ($subfolder.files -ne $null)
        {
            $subfiles=$subfolder.files
            $subfoldername=$subfolder.name
            foreach ($subfile in $subfiles)
                {
                    write-host $subfile.name
                    $b=$subfile.openbinary()
                    $fs=new-object system.io.filestream(("d:\backups\Old_Surveys\Historical Company Surveys\$subfoldername\"+$subfile.name), [system.io.filemode]::create)
                    $bw=new-object system.io.binarywriter($fs)
                    $bw.write($b)
                    $bw.close()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The objective of the code was to iterate down thru any folders, and subfolders of the folders, and create them on the local drive and download any files that are in them at that level. I did this manually for up to 3-sub levels of folders, but if there are more levels lower than that then I would have had to keep manually adding all the code and going even longer. Surely there has to be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a **recursive** function: E.g. `Download($Folder) {...}`. In the function, download the files and if you find a subfolder, call the function itself with the subfolder as argument: `Download $SubFolder`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I understand what I have to do, the complexity of it is bending my brain is all. Each time the function is called its going to have to have a new subfolder location on the local drive as well as continue going down the proverbial rabbit hole of more subfolders within subfolders.

Comment: The comment was from a programming point of view. But more from a SharePoint/process point of view: why don't you just open you SharePoint folder in explorer and use cmdlets like [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) and [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7) which both have a `-Recurse` switch.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion and I will give that a try next week when I am back in office.